# Javascript Regex to match key value of JSON

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not really good at regex so I would be grateful if you help me >.<

From my mqtt server, I have this 2 different types of JSON data received.

```
{"type":"aaa","id":"123abc","data":[0.0000,0,1]}
```

and

```
{"data":[0430be588a3700000000000058883700000000]}
```

and what I want is to capture the value of 'data' from these 2 input types where I can see the ff. output

```
"data":[0.0000,0,1]
"data":[0430be588a37000000]
```

I tried the ff. regex to do this

```
/"([_a-z]\w*)":\s*([^,]*)/g
```

Check here: https://regex101.com/r/zmeFRR/1

However, what I received is

```
[0.0000
```

and

```
[0430be588a3700000000000058883700000000]}
```

Can someone help me try to resolve this?

PS.
I tried to use JSON.parse on this data since I thought it would be easier to parse data, but because of the type of data I received, data":[0430be588a37000000], this won't do. That's why I tried regex instead.

Comment: That's why it's not JSON

Comment: Parsing JSON with regex is too fragile. Try fixing the JSON string first. Say, if you have hex values (with length more than `8`) in between brackets, then you can use `text.replace(/\[([a-fA-F0-9]{8,})]/g, '[$1]')` (of if the values should just contain one letter: `/\[(\d*[a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]*)]/g`) and then parse with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: `/"data":\[[^\]]*\]/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the negated character class in the capture group `([^,]*)` matches 0+ times any char except a comma, which can not cross matching the comma in `0.0000,0,1`

You could get either the value between double quotes, or the value between the square brackets:

```
"([_a-z]\w*)":\s*("[^"]*"|\[[^]\[]*])
```

- `"` Match `"`
- `([_a-z]\w*)` Capture **group 1**, match a single char being either `_` or a-z followed by optional word chars
- `":\s*` Match `":` and optional whitespace chars
- `("[^"]*"|\[[^]\[]*])` Capture **group 2**, match either from `".."` or `[..]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BybcVx/1)

Comment: your regex seems to work in regex101 site so I tried to translate it to my Javascript code but it seems like the only data successfully parsed are 'type' and 'id', the data is 'undefined'. I'm curious, do you think there are some provisions when translating regex into js code?

Comment: @MariY I forgot an extra escape for Javascript. It should be like this `"([_a-z]\w*)":\s*("[^"]*"|\[[^\]\[]*])` https://regex101.com/r/uXGD4G/1